# Ruby on Rails: Devise Authentication with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

In my RoR project, the user could drag and drop a JavaScript link to the browser's bookmark manager/bar.

The JavaScript link calls another JavaScript file, say `LoadUserData.js`.

I'm using Devise for authentication.

My question is: when the user click the bookmark:

1. If the user has logged in, the user data will be loaded;
2. Otherwise, the bookmark will redirect the user to the login page.

How to implement it?

Peter

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: We are currently using the JavaScript to load a Flash front end, and in the Flash, we can request user data from the server.  If the user has not logged, it will return 401 not authorized. I think in the JavaScript, you could also request the user data from the server, but in my project we don't do this. If you want, I think a jQuery `$.ajax` should do it.